# What insulation materials for converted vans?

Tags: insulation, walls, ceiling, floor

I want to add insulation to the ceiling, walls, and floor of my van as a first step to convert it.

What are the recommended/available materials for that aim?

---

By "convert" I mean to turn a regular vehicle into a something one can live in. Like this sweet Mercedes Sprinter below :)

[image: Mercedes Sprinter converted]

Answer (score 3):

Answering my own question as I did quite a lot of online research on that topic.

I did this across different languages (English, French & German) which was interesting: habits/technics seem to vary from one country to another.

---

### Criterias & vocabulary

#### Criterias

- Thermal insulation: must be excellent
- Resistance to humidity: must be excellent
- Compression potential: your vehicle vibrates a lot, over time the insulating material might get very compressed (i.e. [rockwool](https://www.google.com/search?q=fiberglass&biw=1259&bih=794&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwjOrP-KtsPOAhXiA8AKHZjfBtMQ_AUIBygC#tbm=isch&q=rockwool)). So you might want to avoid materials that compress a lot, at least for the walls.
- Sound insulation: a great plus

#### Insulation-related scientific terms

- **Thermal Conductivity**: the lower the value, the better
- **Thermal Resistance**: the higher the value, the better
- **Specific Heat Capacity**: the higher the value, the better
- **Thermal Diffusivity**: the lower the value, the better

Eco-friendliness values:

- **Embodied Carbon & EPDs**: carbon associated with making the material, [read more](http://www.greenspec.co.uk/building-design/embodied-energy/)

---

## Insulating materials list

#### Cork sprayed

[image: Cork sprayed insulation]

Thermal conductivity at 0 °C: around 0.043W/(m K)

**Price:** in France, [suber-spray.com](http://www.suber-spray.com/spip.php?page=produit) sells a bucket of 12Kg for 215€ which can cover around 6 square meters if applying 2 layers (recommended). So a cost of **36€ per square meter** if applying 2 layers (without adding the cost of renting/buying the gear to apply it).

**Pros:**

- can reach any tiny part, great to avoid [thermal bridges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_bridge)
- fast to apply
- apply the thickness you want by doing as many layers as you need
- [cork has many eco-friendly features](https://www.bangorcork.com/cork-uses-6673), from production to destruction (recycling)
- good sound insulation
- can be the colour you like

**Cons:**

- usually more expensive than other insulating materials
- need of gear to apply it: spray gun, compressor, drill with mixer

Example of usage on vans: [suber-spray.com/spip.php?rubrique10](http://suber-spray.com/spip.php?rubrique10)

Tip: it's expensive, so you might want to use a cheaper isolating material for the flat parts to be isolated, and this for the smaller hard-to-reach/hard-to-insulate parts.

Note: This insulating material is often use in sailing boats.

**Buy sprayed cork:**

- in USA: [vipeqindustries.com](http://www.vipeqindustries.com/)
- in Germany: [kork.net](http://kork.net), see [shop.korkmosaik.com/Korkgranulat](http://shop.korkmosaik.com/Korkgranulat)
- in Canada: [sprayedcorkresolution.ca](http://sprayedcorkresolution.ca/)
- in Italy: [diasen.com](https://www.diasen.com/sp/en/diathonite-cork-render-spray-application.3sp)
- in France: [suber-spray.com](http://www.suber-spray.com/spip.php?page=produit)
- in France: [alsacork.fr](http://www.alsacork.fr/boutique-online/catalog/liege-projet%C3%A9)

---

#### Cork rolls/sheets

[image: Cork rolls insulation]

[image: Cork rolls insulation applied in van]

Thermal conductivity at 0 °C: around 0.043W/(m K)

Exists in different thicknesses, but the ticker the less flexible.

**Price:** 2 mm thickness, 150 x 50 cm = 10€

**Pros:**

- good sound insulation
- easy to buy (your local DIY shop)
- [cork has many eco-friendly features](https://www.bangorcork.com/cork-uses-6673), from production to destruction (recycling)

**Cons:**

- mostly good for flat parts, otherwise time consuming (1 month, 4h per day for this Mercedes Sprinter [youtube.com/watch?v=jAmyxwGx7aU](http://youtube.com/watch?v=jAmyxwGx7aU))

---

#### Reimo X Trem isolator

[image: Reimo X Trem isolator]

[image: Reimo X Trem isolator applied in van]

Thermal conductivity: 0,020 - 0,034 W/mK (maybe around 0.03 at 0°C?).

Made of expanded polyethylene.

Sold as roll.

A product of Reimo, a German shop specialized in converted vehicles.

Data sheet - [ihr-business-im-internet.de/anwendungen/ms-visucom/bilder/firma70/EN/zubehoerprofi/276.pdf](http://ihr-business-im-internet.de/anwendungen/ms-visucom/bilder/firma70/EN/zubehoerprofi/276.pdf)

**Price:** 15€ per sq meter of 20mm thick - on [campingshopwagner.de/product_info.php?info=p4340](http://campingshopwagner.de/product_info.php?info=p4340)

**Pros:**

- simple to put
- good sound insulation

**Cons:**

- may be difficult to obtain outside of Germany
- mostly good for flat parts, otherwise time consuming

**Buy Reimo X Trem isolator:**

- in Germany: [campingshopwagner.de](http://campingshopwagner.de/product_info.php?info=p4340)
- in France: [h2r-equipements.com](http://h2r-equipements.com/isolation-pour-camping-car-fourgon/5481-reimo-x-trem-isolator-plaque-de-1-x-2-m.html)
- in France: [reimo.com/fr](https://www.reimo.com/fr/D-accessoires_camping/DW-amenagement_interieur/DWC-isolation_finition/)
- in UK: [reimo.com/en](http://reimo.com/en/D-camping_shop/DW-van_conversion_parts_accessories/DWC-thermal_insulation/)

---

#### Aeroflex FIRO

[image: Aeroflex FIRO insulation]

[image: Aeroflex FIRO insulation applied in van]

Thermal conductivity at 0 °C: 0,034 W/mK

Sold as roll.

Data sheet: [aeroflex.nl/en/products/aeroflex-firo](http://aeroflex.nl/en/products/aeroflex-firo).

**Price:** usually around 10€ per square meter when 19mm thick.

**Pros:**

- simple to put
- good sound insulation
- different thicknesses available
- self glueing available
- clean & aesthetically pleasing

**Cons:**

- mostly good for flat parts, otherwise time consuming

**Tip:** buy self gluing version to make things simpler.

Example usage on a Ford Transit : [verpiss-dich-von-meiner-veranda.de/post/188/wohnmobil-isolierung/](http://verpiss-dich-von-meiner-veranda.de/post/188/wohnmobil-isolierung/)

**Buy Aeroflex FIRO:**

- in Germany: [ebay.de](http://ebay.de/itm/301997671514)
- in Germany: [amazon.de](http://amazon.de/dp/B00KLGDYL0)
- in Germany: [hood.de](http://hood.de/i/aeroflex-firo-19mm-kartoninhalt-8qm-w-armaflex-kaiflex-endlosplatte-selbstklebend-52403365.htm)

---

#### Armaflex (product of Armacell)

[image: Armaflex insulation]

[image: Armaflex insulation applied in van]

Thermal conductivity at 0 °C: 0,036 W/mK

**Price:** 10€ per square meter - [ebay.de/itm/like/271583864528](http://ebay.de/itm/like/271583864528)

Sold as roll.

**Pros:**

- simple to put, just cut to the shape you like
- good sound insulation
- different thicknesses available
- self glueing available
- clean & aesthetically pleasing

**Cons:**

- mostly good for flat parts, otherwise time consuming

Armaflex "AF series" - [armaflex.com/www/armacell/INETFAQ.nsf/IDP/478F84DCC0A98ED6C1256CD700600264](http://armaflex.com/www/armacell/INETFAQ.nsf/IDP/478F84DCC0A98ED6C1256CD700600264)

Buy Armaflex:

- in Germany: [amazon.de](http://amazon.de/dp/B015ODM7GC)
- in Germany: [ebay.de](http://ebay.de/itm/like/271583864528)

---

#### Polyurethane foam

[image: Polyurethane foam insulation applied in a van]

Thermal conductivity at 0 °C: around 0.025W/(m K)

**Pros:**

- good sound insulation
- can expand 50 times more, i.e. a 1L of product can produce 50L of foam
- can "fill" an empty area, filling even the smallest cavities

**Cons:**

- can deform the car body when added
- prevent future car body work (in case of accident) on parts having that foam
- compresses over time? (TBC)

[Polyurethane on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyurethane)

---

#### Thin multi-layer insulation

[image: Thin multi-layer insulation]

[image: Thin multi-layer insulation applied in van]

Price: 5 à 15€ per square meter, according to number of layers & materials used.

**Pros:** very thin.

**Cons:** 
 - poor sound insulation
 - fragile, so must covered by something almost straight away to avoid damaging it

Example usage: [isere-evasion.com/isolation.htm](http://isere-evasion.com/isolation.htm)

Example product: [castorama.fr/store/Isolant-mince-multicouche-17-prod250073.html](http://castorama.fr/store/Isolant-mince-multicouche-17-prod250073.html)

Which country use it in converted van:

- France, no idea why. There are [big debates on French van conversion forum about the actual effectiveness of this material](http://www.mercotribe.net/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=23444).
- USA, I think they use something similar called "Refletix".

---

#### Denim isolation

[image: Denim isolation]

[image: Denim isolation applied in van]

**Pros:** eco-friendly.

I just came across that material & thought it probably was worth mentioning it as it's very eco-friendly. Further research on its characteristics is needed though.

[hurriedyear.com/2016/02/10/insulating-a-sprinter-van/](http://hurriedyear.com/2016/02/10/insulating-a-sprinter-van/)

[ecohabitation.com/actualite/nouvelles/isolation-coton-recycle-choix-ecolo](http://ecohabitation.com/actualite/nouvelles/isolation-coton-recycle-choix-ecolo)

---

### More insulating materials

- "Trocellen"
- "KFLEX"
- Sheep's wool

---

### My biased opinion

I think the best is to use **Reimo X Trem isolator** (or Armaflex or Aeroflex FIRO) and afterwards add some **sprayed cork** in the parts you could not cover.

By adding sprayed cork on these parts that couldn't be covered, you'll reduce the [thermal bridges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_bridge), or completely eliminate them if you put enough layers.

---

### Resources

- [greenspec.co.uk/building-design/insulation-materials-thermal-properties/](http://www.greenspec.co.uk/building-design/insulation-materials-thermal-properties/)
- [trafic-amenage.com/physique/thermique-isolation.html (FRENCH)](http://trafic-amenage.com/physique/thermique-isolation.html)

Comment: Have you made a decision on what to use?

Comment: Yes, I used Armaflex. I liked the fact that it's easy to install (cut & apply), very clean (didn't need to apply a "proper" wall straight after, it's a good sound insulator, it's affordable, it comes in different thicknesses, it does not burn easily, and so on. I might apply sprayed cork later in the difficult parts that I couldn't cover.

Answer (score 1):

Given that the main criterior for insulating a van are going to be weight and thickness (so that you don't lose too much space inside), I'd suggest you want the higest insulation-density you can get - so something like Celotex or Kingspan or other similar brands of rigid foam-board insulation.

They'll be more expensive than other types, but also get you a lot more insulation for the same thickness (or less thickness, and weight, for the same amount of insulation)

Comment: Makes sense. Do you have links to some technical documentation regarding those materials?